# How to check if the selected date is smallest of all the available dates in Dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop-down list where i am having few dates.
How to check if the selected date is smallest of all the available dates in Dropdown list

Comment: What have you tried? It's as trivial as `if (selectedDate == allDates.Min())`.

Comment: You can use [`Enumerable.Min`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min.aspx) as per @CodeCaster suggested

Answer (score 0):

What i understood by your question is, you want to check if the selected date is the smallest of all options on any front-end language, below is the code to check it in JQuery

```
selectedValue = Date.parse($("#dropdown").val());
isSmallest = true;

$("#dropdown option").each(function(){
    if(Date.parse($(this).val()) < selectedValue){
        isSmallest = false;
    }
})

if(isSmallest === true){
    //Selected date is smallest
}
else{
    //Selected date is not smallest
}
```

Please respond if I misunderstood your question or if you want me to explain the code above